# Multi Tenency Scenario with WAAD in Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, exchange-server, multi-tenant

We are planning a new multi tenency azure application based on ASP.NET MVC.
The customer data must be completely separated from each other. Customer A may know nothing about customer B nor its existance.

In addition to our business logic the customer may create own users and groups, maintain private contacts and calendars with user management.
To meet these criteria, I would like to use the Active Directory and the Exchange Server. According to my research the Exchange Server 2013 is capable of multiple tenents and domains.

So my idea is the following 
I'm not able to post images. So please take a look to http://img144.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=551844509_AD_Structure_122_27lo.jpg

1. A main domain is created in Azure (parent domain)
2. users in this domain are just for our global app support
3. Each customer is sperated into its own active directory child domain

   - Our support has administrative privleges in each customer domain
   - Customer has a single admin account and is able to creates several users and groups
   - He can discover his domain, but not other customer domains or the parent domain
4. A Exchange Server 2013 server is installed on a VM.

   - each customer domain is connected to the exchange (multi tenency feature)
   - contacts, tasks and calendars are managed with exchange for each customer
   - customer A is not able to discover and cannot find any other customer or his data
5. login will be done with WIF and user will intact as domain user in his own domain
6. We do not want to use Office 365

Is this scenario and structure possible? And it is possible with Azure?
We will migrate about 3-5000 customers to this application and we will grow up the next years up to 20.000 customers.

Other features would be nice:

- We want to host our own database servers in our datacenters and connect them through VPN to our Azure Application to prevent copies of them to the U.S. by Microsoft

  - Same for shared files and customer files
- Single Sign On from customer site to the application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scenario is possible and can be done within Azure. You can also connect your datacenter via VPN to Azure. As for SSO support within your application, that's up to you to build in, but is doable. One thing I can point out without knowing too much about your application and what you're actually trying to build as far as an end product is concerned is that you'll have to take into account the per user license ramifications for the Exchange portion. It sounds like you're leveraging Exchange for most features minus mail. You'll need to look into SPLA if you haven't done so already.

Another item to point out is the density per server with Exchange. You don't go into detail of what your Exchange architecture looks like so I assume you're installing an Exchange server with all roles on a single server.

At the moment, I would say your design is at its rough stages and needs to be worked out into some more detail to ensure what you're trying to do is practical and that the tools you're using are the correct ones for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
It is not possible to explain the application logic, but that is not important at this point. It is a very specific process for the industial usage only.
We need to build a multi tenency system and would like to use existing features of azure or Microsoft products.

Comment: Yes, we would like to use active directory for users and groups and the role management, also the user authentication. No other requirements at this point.
We just do not wand to hold the user management data in any of our databases.
For the application features 'Contacts, Calendars" we would like to use the exchange features.
Yes, we do not need any mail services here. 

The licensing is not important right now and is not in my hand.
That's a task for our IT department and the EA. We are just the developers.